# How to perform a APC 9617 Reset?

Tags: ups, serial, password-reset, apc-smart-ups

I've locked myself out of an APC 9617 management card.  Trying to figure out how to reset the password, or even the card to factory defaults.  All the documentation I can find says to connect to the serial interface on the 9617 and initiate a reset with the pin-hole button.  However, the card has no serial interface.  Tried connecting a serial cable to the UPS itself, and somehow managed to send a shutdown command to it (so much for our network stack).

So - has anyone done a reset on a 9617?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default username:password on the APC card is `apc:apc`.

You can configure it through the UPS it's installed in via the proper APC (black) serial cable. Please don't use a generic 9-pin cable. You'll need to connect using a terminal emulation program (minicom, cKermit, Hyperterminal, screen, etc.). The key to doing this is *stopping powerchute* (or any UPS control software on the server connected to the UPS), setting the BAUD rate to *2400* instead of *9600*, and pressing the reset button on the interface card. You should be able to navigate the resulting text menus to gain IP information and reconfigure user names/passwords.

From the [documentation for the AP9617 card](http://www.apcmedia.com/salestools/ASTE-6Z5QDZ_R0_EN.pdf),

```
5. Press the Reset button. The Status LED will flash 
alternately orange and green. Press the Reset button a 
second time immediately while the LED is flashing to 
reset the user name and password to their defaults 
temporarily.

6. Press ENTER as many times as necessary to redisplay the 
User Name prompt, then use the default, apc, for the 
user name and password. (If you take longer than 30 
seconds to log on after the User Name prompt is 
redisplayed, you must repeat step 5 and log on again.
```

Comment: Great, thank you.  I will re-emphasize the importance of the APC-specific serial cable :).

Answer (score 0):

The serial cable I just used to complete this task was an APC# 940-0024C clone I built as per the pinout found here:
https://networkupstools.org/cables.html

apc:apc worked as the default user/pass after resetting the network interface with a paperclip.

*This method was required when the APC locating tool did not find the UPS with just a laptop and the UPS connected to a switch. Both mac and IP scans were attempted. The UPS was found set for a 10.22.x.x address so a full IP scan would have taken an unreasonable time.